# Excel UDF that accepts both Range and Array as Parameter like 'SUM'

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I an writing a UDF that needs to accept both Arrays and Ranges.

Usually declaring parameter as variant would work but a Range is an object so this no longer applies. That being said bellow I pasted code that only works when passing an array.
Here is theorethical example, based on `SUM`:

```
Function TSUM(numbers() As Variant) As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To UBound(numbers, 1)
        TSUM = TSUM + numbers(i)
    Next i
End Function
```

> =TSUM({1,1})   Returns 2
>   =TSUM(A1:B1)   Returns #VALUE!

So how can I fix above example to accept Ranges as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are content to sum the array/range item by item, I would just change to using a For Each loop that works well for either Ranges or Arrays.

Here is that version

```
Public Function TSUM(numbers As Variant) As Variant
    Dim i As Variant

    For Each i In numbers
        TSUM = TSUM + i
    Next i
End Function
```

If you generally want to work a function  based on the type of the argument, you can use `TypeName()` and switching logic.  Here is you function with that approach.  I called it TSUM2 for uniqueness.

```
Public Function TSUM2(numbers As Variant) As Variant
    Dim i As Integer

    If TypeName(numbers) = "Range" Then
        TSUM2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(numbers)
    Else
        For i = 1 To UBound(numbers, 1)
            TSUM2 = TSUM2 + numbers(i)
        Next i
    End If
End Function
```

Note in both examples, I removed the parentheses from the numbers parameters (was `numbers() as Variant` before).  This allows it to accept Range inputs.

If you take the second approach, be sure to debug and verify the TypeNames that could come through.

Comment: This works fine if you're working with a single argument, but if the function takes more than one argument you'll need to keep a counter in the for loop to access the Nth element of each range / array and that is a bit trickier

Comment: @AndreTerra, are you referring to a `ParamArray` or simply a UDF that takes multiple parameters?

Comment: @ByronWall I meant an UDF that takes multiple parameters, but my comment is incorrect.. I think I commented without reading the second snippet which has a loop counter that could be used to access `secondparameter(i)`

Comment: Coming back to this answer (and seeing my own comment from a couple years ago!), I do find that the way the question was phrased isn't ideal because it doesn't require the answer to deal with the need to write logic that can process either an array or a range. If `Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum()` did not exist, would you simply duplicate your code within the `TypeName` check and handle it with `Range.Cells`? I find that for complex formulas this quickly becomes repetitive, error prone or not flexible. I'd just like to write a single `MyUDF(foo)` and use it both in the Workbook and in VBA..